# tMysqlOutput component is doing Auto Commit when the TMysqlConnection hasn't check that option

Tags: talend

I've got a parent job where inside are the Mysql connection components and a tRun component which is relating through a "onSubJobOk" with a tMysqlCommit and with a "onSubJobError" with a "tMysqlRollback".

The fact is when in the child job (tRun in parent) goes well, it seems that the tMysqlCommit is doing its job, but after several tests I've discovered that if I desactivate the tMysqlCommit, the tMysqlOutput in my child job is still doing it, so...

I don't know how, and I don't know why the tMysqlOutput is still doing the commit.

If you need more info, or some screenshots about my job, just say it.

Thanks for your time and your attention!

Comment: Hi PataToT. Maybe "Autocommit" option is enable in your tMySqlConnection componant? Normally, you can't have "Autocommit" option + tMySqlCommit component activated in the same time without obtain a error.

Comment: Hi @Mo2s, thanks for your quick response. No, I've got the "Autocommit" option disabled in my tMysqlConnection component.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback PataToT. On the off chance, have you check the "Commit every" option in the Advanced Options tab, in the tMySqlOutput Component? (https://community.talend.com/t5/Design-and-Development/Talend-Auto-commit-for-MySql-Connections/td-p/72685)

Comment: Hi!

I discovered my problem, sorry about that but I had got a tMysqlOutput with the "truncate" mode activated in "Action table" option, as a consequence and with all the logic, when tMysqlRollback tryed to run, it didnt work, and the others "tMysqlOutputs" (with no "trucate" mode) didn't work either.

When I changed it to "none" mode, the rollback goes without problems.

Thanks for your time @Mo2s

Answer (score 0):

I discovered my problem, sorry about that but I had got a tMysqlOutput with the "truncate" mode activated in "Action table" option, as a consequence and with all the logic, when tMysqlRollback tryed to run, it didnt work, and the others "tMysqlOutputs" (with no "trucate" mode) didn't work either. When I changed it to "none" mode, the rollback goes without problems. Thanks for your time @Mo2s